# How to fix the location of user.config file for personalization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf

I am trying to save personalized data using `ApplicationSettingsBase`. This was done by fetching personalized data using indexer `object this[string propertyName]` of `ApplicationSettingBase` and saving the personalized data using  `ApplicationSettingBase` save call.

A property annotated as `[UserScopedSetting]` is used as personalized data which is saved and read.

The data is saved and fetched from user.config file saved in below location:

C:\Users\**loggedInUser**\AppData\Local\**fixed string**\**Exe Name appeneded with hash**\**dll version**\User.Config

**Question:**

Using `ApplicationSettingsBase`, I would like to be able to change the default path where the settings are stored.

Link questions on similar lines:

[When using a Settings.settings file in .NET, where is the config actually stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075204/when-using-a-settings-settings-file-in-net-where-is-the-config-actually-stored)

[Sharing settings between applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367519/sharing-settings-between-applications)

Comment: That link doesn't explain how to change the location of the settings files, does it? It only describes where they are stored by default according the type of application.

Comment: @Isma yes, it just tells where to look for the file.

Comment: @bommelding  Fixing the location will solve many problems for me as i will have control on the location.One scenario, want to read the file from another exe.

Comment: @RiteshKumar: Did you try to use a custom provider as I suggested or what happened?

Comment: @mm8 Not yet , but looks like this should solve...Thanks!! . Will mark it as answer once i try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to write a custom [SettingsProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.settingsprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2) class and replace the default `LocalFileSettingsProvider` with this one in your setting class, e.g.:

```
public class MyUserSettings : ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    public MyUserSettings()
        : base()
    {
        Providers.Clear();
        Providers.Add(new CustomProvider());
    }
    ...
}
```